# Using hidden input to preserve form contents

Tags: php, html, forms

I am currently working on a small signup sheet for a bigger project which will integrate it, and I'm trying to figure out how to integrate a hidden form field(s) into it, to preserve data across submissions. Basically, whenever someone signs up on the form, their name should appear next to the entry, and that entry should not change when the next person submits the form (i.e., it shouldn't become available again). This is what I am working with so far:

```
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Select from one of the following:<br>
    <fieldgroup>
        <?php

            $form_contents = "";

            if (isset($_POST['food']) && $_POST['food'] == 'pasta') {
                $form_contents .= "<input type='hidden'>Pasta - " . $_POST['name'] . "<br>";
            } else {
                $form_contents .= '<input type="radio" name="food" value="pasta">Pasta</input><br>';
            }

            if (isset($_POST['food']) && $_POST['food'] == 'salad') {
                $form_contents .= "Salad - " . $_POST['name'] . "<br>";
            } else {
                $form_contents .= '<input type="radio" name="food" value="salad">Salad</input><br>';
            }

            if (isset($_POST['food']) && $_POST['food'] == 'burgers') {
                $form_contents .= "Burgers - " . $_POST['name'] . "<br>";
            } else {
                $form_contents .= '<input type="radio" name="food" value="burgers">Burgers</input><br>';
            }

            echo $form_contents;
        ?>
    </fieldgroup>
```

Currently, this form stores an initial entry, but the next time I submit it, that name is erased and the selection becomes available again. Is there any way to keep that entry so that it is preserved every time the form is submitted? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look up `<label>` tags for your visible inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea with `<input type="hidden" />` works well.

Maybe you can take a look how `<input>` works, right [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). You don't have to do it like `<input></input>`, just give the input a name and a value.

Every submit, you can check if a current variable is already given. When it is, you can set a `<input type="hidden" />` with that variable, when it isn't, you can give the user the possibility to enter a name in `<input type="text" />`.

---

In response to your comment, you maybe can try this. I think that it does what you're looking for. Probably, it isn't the most attractive solution, but I think it'll work.

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Select from one of the following:<br>
<fieldgroup>
    <?php
        # Set empty form
        $_Form  = NULL;

        # Check submit
        if(isset($_POST['food'])) {

            # Check pasta
            if($_POST['food'] == 'pasta') {

                $_Form  .= '<input type="hidden" name="foodSelectedPasta" value="Pasta - ' . $_POST['name'] . '">Pasta - ' . $_POST['name'] . '</input><br>';

            } else {

                # Check already chosen
                if(isset($_POST['foodSelectedPasta'])) {
                    $_Form  .= '<input type="hidden" name="foodSelectedPasta" value="' . $_POST['foodSelectedPasta'] . '">' . $_POST['foodSelectedPasta'] . '</input><br>';

                } else {
                    $_Form  .= '<input type="radio" name="food" value="pasta">Pasta</input><br>';
                }
            }

            # Check salad
            if($_POST['food'] == 'salad') {

                $_Form  .= '<input type="hidden" name="foodSelectedSalad" value="Salad - ' . $_POST['name'] . '">Salad - ' . $_POST['name'] . '</input><br>';

            } else {

                # Check already chosen
                if(isset($_POST['foodSelectedSalad'])) {
                    $_Form  .= '<input type="hidden" name="foodSelectedSalad" value="' . $_POST['foodSelectedSalad'] . '">' . $_POST['foodSelectedSalad'] . '</input><br>';

                } else {
                    $_Form  .= '<input type="radio" name="food" value="salad">Salad</input><br>';
                }
            }

            # Check burgers
            if($_POST['food'] == 'burgers') {

                $_Form  .= '<input type="hidden" name="foodSelectedBurgers" value="Burgers - ' . $_POST['name'] . '">Burgers - ' . $_POST['name'] . '</input><br>';
            } else {

                # Check already chosen
                if(isset($_POST['foodSelectedBurgers'])) {
                    $_Form  .= '<input type="hidden" name="foodSelectedBurgers" value="' . $_POST['foodSelectedBurgers'] . '">' . $_POST['foodSelectedBurgers'] . '</input><br>';
                } else {
                    $_Form  .= '<input type="radio" name="food" value="burgers">Burgers</input><br>';
                }
            }

        } else {
            $_Form  .= '<input type="radio" name="food" value="pasta">Pasta</input><br>';
            $_Form  .= '<input type="radio" name="food" value="salad">Salad</input><br>';
            $_Form  .= '<input type="radio" name="food" value="burgers">Burgers</input><br>';
        }

        # Output form
        echo $_Form;
    ?>
</fieldgroup>
```

Comment: How would I apply this to the entries though? I want the user to be able to enter their name and select an item to sign up with, and if that item is already taken, it should display the name of the person who selected it, and not have the option to be selected again. Would I use the `hidden` tag on those entries when I check them after the form is submitted?

Comment: Ah well, now I understand your correct meaning. So you have multiple options for food and every person can select a different one. So when Person 1 selects Pasta and submits, Person 2 can't select Pasta anymore.

Comment: Correct. I'm trying to use the `hidden` attribute somehow so that the data is preserved and the user can see who has signed up for what, and they can choose from the other selections available, which would be preserved across form submissions

Comment: This works with the input I have so far. Would I be able to use this same logic and extrapolate it into a function, to address any number of inputs?

Comment: Yes of course. As you can see, the script contains 3 times the same pattern with a check and a form output. When you put this check into a function, you can use it as many times as you want.

Comment: @user3380461 sounds like you should use a database to keep track of all the entries?

Comment: I'm confused as to how I'd setup the parameters though. I know that I need to pass in the POST information, but how would I check each of the inputs if they are appended to a string?

Comment: @Terminus when he wants to check it over the whole website, he has to use a database indeed. It sounds to me that he wants to check it on just one computer, on only one page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all of this on a single page, you can change the name attribute of the hidden elements to be arrays. Then, check if a particular field has been set in the array before deciding whether to echo the hidden element again or echoing out the radio button.

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Select from one of the following:<br>
<fieldgroup>
<?php
    $form_contents = "";

    // you only showed the options for food but you can extend this by adding the other fields to this array
    $alreadySelected = array(
        'food'=>array()
    );

    if(isset($_POST['selected']))
        $alreadySelected = array_merge_recursive($alreadySelected,$_POST['selected']);

    if(!empty($_POST['food']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $alreadySelected['food'][$_POST['food']] = $_POST['name'];
    }
    // do some error checking
    else if(!empty($_POST['name']) && empty($_POST['food'])) {
        echo "<span style='color:red'>You need to pick a food when you enter your name.</span><br/>";
    }
    else if(empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['food'])) {
        echo "<span style='color:red'>Please enter your name when you pick a food</span>.<br/>";
    }

    // use the label as the key and the value of the input as the value
    $foods = array(
         'Pasta'=>'pasta'
        ,'Salad'=>'salad'
        ,'Burgers'=>'burgers'
    );

    foreach($foods as $label=>$value) {
        if(isset($alreadySelected['food'][$value])) {
            // use the name of the person who selected the option as the value so that we can remember it for further submissions
            $form_contents .= "<input type='hidden' name='selected[food][" . $value . "]' value='" . $alreadySelected['food'][$value] . "'>" . $label . " - " . $alreadySelected['food'][$value] . "<br>";
        }
        else {
            $form_contents .= "<label><input type='radio' name='food' value='" . $value . "'>" . $label . "</label><br>";
        }
    }

    echo $form_contents;
?>
</fieldgroup>
```