# execute PHP form on Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

please excuse my English - I have created a _POST form  where the user can fill in two numerical fields, which are then multiplied and divided by some constants to output the result when the form is submitted. I am executing the form on the same page using
    ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); 
The code is very basic and works on the servers where I tested it (can copy and paste if required).

Now I'd like to use this small "calculator" on a Wordpress page (I am running Avada theme) but I'm at a complete loss as to how to substitute ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).

I have tried: 
- copying and pasting the whole snippet as it is in the Code Block of fusion builder > I get an error
- storing the variables and calculations in a separate .php file to be called - hardcoded or using  bloginfo() funtion 
- creating a new template page with the code embedded

...but when I submit the form I am only redirected to the additional php file or to the homepage.

Am I trying to do something completely wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated as I really don't understand how this could work...

Many thanks!

Comment: Here is a good discussion of why it may not be such a good idea to leave it blank, though it will work. It opens you up to hijacking and inject attack. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-an-empty-url-for-a-html-forms-action-attribute-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested this on a WordPress page template.

Make sure it is not put inside the loop!

I have put a simple calculation and when you submit the number input to this the result is echoed - that can obviously have a span put around it or whatever it needs. The calculation could have whatever you want in it.

You should also be able to `include` your calculation sheet:

`include "calculations.php";`

These are some security considerations surrounding the use of `includes` http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=144

PHP_SELF went to index.php as that is the master template.

You need to use `<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>` if you want to use that for the action to make it work fully programatically, but the hard-coded URL should work (not best practice though and `REQUEST_URI` does work).

If you use it you need to use the built in WordPress escape for the URI to sanitize it as you will be "getting" whatever is in it.

```
      <form name="form" action ="<?php echo  esc_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="post">
```

Which effectively gives you:

```
      <form name="form" action ="http://the full url of the page this script is on/" method="post">
      <input type="number" name="number_in">
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </form>

      <?php $result = (int) $_POST['number_in'] * 4; 
      echo $result;
      ?>
```

If you wanted it to consecutively add to the result on each form submission you might need to get a bit trixy with a hidden input or session variable - you can just use:

```
    $_SESSION['number_in'] = $_SESSION['number_in'] + $result;
    echo $_SESSION['number_in'];
```

to keep a running tally of cumulative results, as sessions are already active for WordPress.

The use of (int) performs a type conversion - if you know it will be an integer - otherwise float should do. This should avoid the need to clean up the input any further.  Might be a handy reference on php.net http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

This explains basic usage for hidden inputs.

[Get and echo inputs from textarea repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816772/get-and-echo-inputs-from-textarea-repeatedly/33816873#33816873)

You could, in principle, just leave tha action blank and it will submit to itself `action=""` but here is a good discussion of why it may not be such a good idea to do that. Though it will work, it opens you up to hijacking and inject attack. [stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131781/)

Though you can run php code in WordPress, whether you should or not is a whole different discussion...

Comment: Thanks a lot! very informative, I've looked up the built in WordPress escape for the URI and I've learnt something new on top of solving my problem! I've come across another suggestion while I was at it: simply leave the action field blank - URI references that are blank point to the current resource. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It is better to write your php code in functions.php and create shortcode of that and use that shortcode in page. Example:

```
add_shortcode( 'multiple_enquiry_form', 'enquiry_form' );
function enquiry_form(){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        if(isset($_POST['enquiry_form_submit'])){   
    } ?>    

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post" name="enquiry_form" action='<?php echo get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'enquiry' ) ); ?>'> 
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Project</label>
            <select id='proGroup' name="proGroupForm">
            <option value="">- Select Project -</option>                
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Message</label>
            <textarea name="enq_message"></textarea>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Contact</label>   
            <input type="text" name="contactNumber" placeholder="Contact Number"> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">From</label>  
            <input type="text" name="from_date" class="datepicker" placeholder="From Date"> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">To</label>    
            <input type="text" name="to_date" class="datepicker" placeholder="To Date"> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="enquiry_form_submit" value="Send" ng-click="submitted=true">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's hope I understand you correct.

You can't run PHP inside a Wordpress post or page. It's not built that way.

Create a shortcode inside your `functions.php`. This allows you to call functions from within posts and pages. You've might have seen them. Looks like `[gallery limit="5"]`
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/

If your REALLY want to run PHP inside your page. Check out https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I created a shortcode in the functions.php, so simple yet I did not think about it at all!