# jQuery Soccer Timer

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm working with my blog (dedicated to Liverpool FC) and all I want to do is to put a simple time counter on a paragraph (nothing sophisticated). I've done some work around with some scripts but I want something even simpler, but I'm struggling with that.

I need a counter that starts at a specified time, counts up to 45 minutes, then pause for 15 minutes and resume up to 90 minutes.

I need to put it here:

[image]

That's it, any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: The picture says absolutely nothing, paste your HTML code (only the important part) so we can see the classes and id and all that good stuff so we can write a good code for you to use. Btw, let's go reds!... also, do you mind JavaScript? I know jQuery anyway.

Comment: This might be useful for how to set up a timer - this one only counts seconds but has a link to another timer script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241575/php-session-variable-not-parsing-but-isset-says-it-is-running-at-0/34248806#34248806