# Go to next page after this seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I been searching around for a simple code but yet I don't found one that is working for me. I tried using **setInterval** but turn out the code didn't do well.

```
<?php switch(n){ case 1: //do this; //then go to next page after this seconds; } ?>
```

I tried to put javascript into the switch..case,

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>setInterval(location.href = 'goHere.php', 3000);
</script>"
```

it direct me into the next page without counting down. Any solutions?

Comment: Use `setTimeout` to perform any action after certain timeout...

Comment: This page might have some useful bits for the countdown timer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241575/php-session-variable-not-parsing-but-isset-says-it-is-running-at-0/34248806#34248806

Comment: @RayonDabre I tried using setTimeout it still redirect me without counting the time. Maybe I did it wrong. Thanks anyway :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use header function of php

```
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );
```

and if you wants to use javascript then you can use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href= 'http://www.google.com'; // the redirect goes here

},5000);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks mate for saving my 2 hours of research time.

Comment: @DavidChil then you can vote up and accept  my answer